# Benefits of using Squid proxy in Ubuntu Server

Tags: 11.04, server, webserver, squid

What are some of the benefits of installing Squid Proxy in an Ubuntu Server that is sharing its Internet connection to a group of PCs in a LAN.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. You can use Squid for caching. This means the contents of site A are saved locally at your Squid. When a second user requests site A Squid will deliver the content. So the user has it somewhat faster.
2. You can control the traffic for malicious content and if found, remove it.
3. You can restrict the access to certain websites.
4. Of course there are some „bad“ things Squid allows you to do (Control your users, record which sites they visit etc.).