# how to make home pc into ubuntu server

Tags: server, 13.04

I would like to make one of my home PC into a Ubuntu Server and want to access the server from my laptop. I'm having Ubuntu 13.04 in my laptop and I'm ready to install Ubuntu Server in my home PC.
My pc is installed with 2.6GHz dual core processor, 2GB ram and 250GB hard disk so I think this is well enough to create a server.
Since I'm new to linux environment please give some clear explantion.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please edit the question and indicate what kind of server you want to have? Do you mean a web server, a video and or music server, a file server to keep documents, or some other kind of server?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/245406/how-to-make-a-home-server-using-ubuntu-desktop?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

To create a "simple" sort of server when you already have a monitor and such, just install ubuntu

1. SAMBA will give you file sharing.
2. Subsonic is good for streaming.
3. If you want to use the server from outside your house, learn about your router (port forwarding) and Dynamic DNS.
4. LVM is your friend. -- Learn it.