# Ubuntu Server on Chrome OS/Chromebook?

Tags: server, chromebook, chromeos

You hear everyone talking about wanting Ubuntu on their Chromebook. I'm looking to install the Ubuntu server and completely remove ChromeOS. Is this possible? If so how?

Thank you.

Comment: It depends on the make and model of Chromebook. I am familiar with Acer 720. It is possible on that machine.

Answer (score 1):

I would try keeping Chrome OS because this will avoid having to configure the hardware if you remove it. Then install your preferred Ubuntu flavor via Crouton.

Source: https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton 
View targets or desktop environments:

```
sh ~/Downloads/crouton -t help
```

View available releases (I believe 'help' also works.):

```
 sh ~/Downloads/crouton -r list
```

Then I would just install the needed server packages. [How to make a home server using Ubuntu desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/245406/how-to-make-a-home-server-using-ubuntu-desktop#answer-249383)

You may want to choose to install CLI only and build from there:
https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton#i-dont-always-use-linux-but-when-i-do-i-use-cli 
(The crouton page is full of beneficial info.)

You will want to keep the laptop from sleeping. This may be problematic.
https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/issues/210

It looks like eliminating Chrome OS and just installing Ubuntu is involved and possibly risky.

(If it doesn't work out, you may want to just spend $70 on a Raspberry Pi instead to use as a server.)

I hope it works out!

Comment: Crouton uses ChromOS kernel and is not an official version of Ubuntu. It is off topic here.

Comment: @user68186 Thanks for letting me know. I did not realize that. I now see here:  http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/13756/how-is-this-question-off-topic

Comment: I didn't know with Crouton you could choose your Ubuntu flavor. Thank you @user68186 , I'll get to it know.